# spaces in webbrowser visual basic 2010

Tags: c#, vb.net, iframe

i added these in my application

1. WebbRowser1
2. Buttons
3. TextBox

problem is, when my app loads, it will load iframe from textbox and display it on my webbrowser but it's showing white spaces on my webbrowser

here's my code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

here's spaces showing between iframe and webbrowser 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, use the following were here we set the margin and padding to 0 on the body. I tested this by adding the html below into a project resource

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="" X-UA-Compatible"" content="" IE="10" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Code to load the above from resource

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = My.Resources.Contents
    End Sub
End Class
```